# Important difference between "claim" and "assume" in proofs.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

I was discussing with a TA friend, one of the HW problems was

> Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}$.

Before doing the "$\epsilon, N$" definition proof, the students wrote

> We **claim** that $\lim_{n\rightarrow} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, we show that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} ...$

or

> **Assume** $\lim_{n\rightarrow} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, we show that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} ...$

And my friend said that the 2nd proof with "assume" is not correct, it is proving $A$ implies $A$ which is a flaw in the logic.

But I felt proof 2 is okay in a analysis course.
What do you think about this?

Comment: Sorry, but your friend is right. The words "claim" and "assume" mean totally different things - the second proof is assuming what's supposed to be proved, and that is simply totally wrong.

Comment: Assume is note the correct word - it indicates that you throwing in a premise into the proof (the very statement you're trying to prove). If you on the other hand in the proof doesn't rely on this assumption, then the fault is only the one of using incorrect terminology and could be fixed by just changing a word. But if you on the other hand actually make use of your assumption then you make yourself guilty of circular reasoning.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments.

Comment: You can't "assume" what you have to prove: if you assume a statement you have nothing to prove because you accepted it. On the other hand you can assume the opposite in order to prove by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *assume* is used to indicate that you will proceed taking something as a given. This makes your claim look like part of your argument - and your friend is right that that if this were actually so, it would be a circular argument. You'd usually use that word in a proof for:

> Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $X$ holds. Blah blah blah. Contradiction. Therefore $X$ is false.

Here, you definitely want to write out your *claim* followed by a proof of a claim, which makes clear the relationship between the later words (which are a proof) and the earlier words (which are only there to help the reader understand where you're going).

This said, this is an error likely to throw the reader, but not so much affecting the substance of the proof. There's little argument that it's an error, but not understanding the difference between "assume" and "claim" is a lot less severe than not understanding proof.

Comment: Of course this is true, but I'd argue that marking answer 2 "wrong" without qualification in an intro analysis course is only warranted if the student's argument was actually circular. If their proof was otherwise the same as in answer 1, then their only mistake was a superficial terminology error and the pedagogically appropriate response, in my view, would be to correct their phrasing and affirm the substance of the proof. It would be plainly wrong in a published text, but it's substantively correct– as long as the proof demonstrates comprehension– in a classroom environment.

Comment: @Qalnut I agree; I added a note to the effect, since rereading the question, it seems that that point is relevant. (Where I originally only addressed the purely mathematical content of the question)